# wpf application mvvm how to structure properly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im trying to learn MVVM, but I'm having some trouble. Im new to xaml and c#.

What I have so far:

- A `person` class, that define a person object: name, age and other info
- A model class `people`, owns a private linkedlist (list of person), which also contains methods such as `get`, `remove`, `add` and do some calculations
- a viewmodel class, doing casting/parsing/transforming between xaml behind code and the model.
- A xaml behind code file `mainWindow.xaml.cs`, that listen to button click and such, and invoke methods from the viewModel class, and do some simple binding such as `total.Content = objModelView.getTotal()`.

I didnt use `INotifyPropertyChanged` `ObservableCollection`, still trying to wrap my head around it. While my program does what I want I'm not sure how to structure it better.

Basically I have 2 main questions:

1. I see examples online where people store/initiate the list of items in viewmodel, shouldn't I keep the list in model instead, that should be where all the data be stored right?
2. Let's say I'm suppose to display all the items (in the list of the model class) onto a dataGrid. Right now in my program: mainWindow.xaml.cs will detect the button click, then it ask viewModel to store it in model, if no error then xaml behind code will do
   `people_dataGrid.Items.Add(new person { name = newName, age = newAge, address = newAdd });` Is this bad practice? Dont get how to use ObservableCollection here, can it somehow detect a change in the list of my model class, and then remove and add the rows to the datagrid?

I've been reading for the whole day but I'm struck here, hope I can get some direction

Comment: You NEED to use INPC and ObservableCollection, otherwise it isn't MVVM. MVVM should have all the actions done in the Model, and INPC/INCC is how the View knows that data has changed, and the screen needs updating. It sounds like you are actually writing a MVP application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model stores data, the view display it, the viewmodel is the bridge between the two.

That doesn't mean that the view have a direct access to model data because you don't always need to display all data in model layer. So we have a viewmodel layer that makes only useful information accessible.

The viewmodel is very useful when you want to display the same data multiple times but displayed differently: you don't have to replicate data, you only need to define twice what information you need from those data and how to display them.

What you're doing in your second question is using model in view : This is not MVVM. What you want to do is bind the ItemsSource DP of Datagrid to a list of PersonVM which will fetch information from Person.

You code could be structured like that:

```
public class Person {
    public String Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
}

public class PersonVM {
    public PersonVM(Person model) {
        _model = model;
    }

    private readonly Person _model;
    internal Person Model {get {return _model;}}

    public String Name {
        get { return _model.Name; }
        set { _model.Name = value; }
    }
    public int Age {
        get {return _model.Age;}
        set { _model.Name = value; }
    }
}

//PersonV.xaml

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
</StackPanel>


public class People : ObservableCollection<Person> {

}

public class PeopleVM : ObservableCollection<PersonVM> {

    public PeopleVM(People model) {
        _model = model;
        foreach(Person p in _model) {
            Add(new PersonVM(p));
        }
        _model.CollectionChanged += CollectionChangedHandler;
    }

    private void CollectionChangedHandler(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args) {
        switch (notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs.Action) {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach(People p in args.NewItems) {
                    if(!this.Any(pvm => pvm.Model == p)) {
                        this.Add(new PersonVM(p));
                    }
                }

                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach(People p in args.OldItems) {
                    PersonVM pvm = this.FirstOrDefault(pe => pe.Model == p);
                    if(pvm != null) this.Remove(pvm);
                }
                break;
             case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                Clear();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
    }

    private readonly People _model;
}

//PeopleV.xaml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type PersonVM}">
            <PersonV/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>

public class AppVM {
    public AppVM() {
        People p = ServiceLayer.LoadPeople(); //load people
        People = new PeopleVM(p);
    }

    public PeopleVM People {get; set;};
}

//MainWindow.xaml
<Window ...
    >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:AppVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <PeopleV/>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi nkoniishvt, great answer. But there is a lot of boiler plate, that I would replace with some libraries, such as ReactiveUI.

Comment: @Aron Thank you! I need to take a look at this library, I try too much to use standard way.

Comment: ReactiveUI has a `.CreateDerivedCollection()` extension method that does the `PeopleVM` for you. Then `Fody.PropertyChanged` will automagically implement PropertyChanged for you. Massively saves time.

Comment: Collection sync is annoying using the way I used indeed, I'll look into it

Answer (score 3):

**You aren't using MVVM at all.** It sounds like you are using MVP, which is a completely different pattern.

Before you continue, you need to understand what MVVM was designed for, because its a highly complicated (seemlying over engineered pattern) with a huge number of abstractions just to write the ubiquitous To-Do list.

But you must do all of it, otherwise its not MVVM.

**The Zen of MVVM**

MVVM grew out of the realisation that writing good, bug-free, safe UI code is hard. Testing UI code is harder, and involves hiring human testers, that are slow and can get it wrong.

So the solution that they came up with was simple.

***DON'T WRITE ANY CODE IN YOUR UI***

Done.

Except, not. Now, your UI doesn't do anything, it just looks pretty. So they added an extra layer between the UI and the Program/Business Logic/`Model`, and they called it the `ViewModel`.

The job of the `ViewModel` was to tell the UI what to do. But the trick was to get it to tell the UI what to do, without the `ViewModel` knowing about the UI at all.

(MVP has a similar concept, but the Presenter DOES know about the UI)

By having the `ViewModel` not know about the UI at all, we can write clean code that can easily be debugged and tested using our usual bag of tricks. Such as unit testing, refactoring, static code analysis, dependency injection etc etc...

Times are good!

Except the View Model still doesn't know about the UI. So we know what the UI should look like, but the UI doesn't know, because no one is telling it...

So they added the `Binding` class. The binding class's job is to watch the ViewModel, and then update the UI whenever something changes in the ViewModel.

In the world of MVVM there have been two different approaches to how the Binding class works.

You have the WPF way of doing things, which is to implement an event that tells the Binding class that the ViewModel has been updated. This is fast and flexible, but really annoying to write.

And you have the AngularJS way of doing things, which is to poll the ViewModel for updates. This is ridiculously slow and buggy.

If you have been following me thus far, you will note that MVVM defines a flow of data from your Model to your View. A break in any part of this chain will make it "not work".

**It all so COMPLICATED, why bother?**

The only reason I've found that justifies MVVM's excessive complexity is that you can write a GUI which you can have 90% test coverage, as the view only covers a tiny part of your program.

If you think automated testing is overrated, then you shouldn't use MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your post can be as long as one wishes to explain, perhaps a whole lengthy blog itself. I will try to just answer 2 of your specific questions here. I am not going to show the code for each sub-answer, you have to take it as home work. :)

> I didnt use INotifyPropertyChanged ObservableCollection, still trying
>   to wrap my head around it. While my program does what I want I'm not
>   sure how to structure it better.

Why? If you don't use these magic sticks, it's better you write a WinForms app and not a WPF one. Forget everything and dive into these two. You must (no escape) understand and use them in MVVM/WPF. You can even defer reading my further answer for that matter.

> I see examples online where people store/initiate the list of items in
>   viewmodel, shouldn't I keep the list in model instead, that should be
>   where all the data be stored right?

They are not wrong. `Person` class in model layer represents a real world entity and is must, however, I would not bother about having `People` class in model. It's just a collection that could easily be accommodated by ViewModel. I personally would prefer that way always.

> Let's say I'm suppose to display all the items (in the list of the
>   model class) onto a dataGrid. Right now in my program:
>   mainWindow.xaml.cs will detect the button click, then it ask viewModel
>   to store it in model, if no error then xaml behind code will do
>   people_dataGrid.Items.Add(new person { name = newName, age = newAge,
>   address = newAdd }); Is this bad practice? Dont get how to use
>   ObservableCollection here, can it somehow detect a change in the list
>   of my model class, and then remove and add the rows to the datagrid?

That's not MVVM, trust me. At the maximum what you should be required to write in view code behind, is initializing view model and setting it as view's data context.

To handle view events (`Button.Click` for ex) you should use `ICommand` implementation that will be bound to `Button.Command` property in XAML. This way you decouple control's event handler from the code behind.

You need to have a `ObservableCollection<Person>` in your viewmodel which will be bound the `DataGrid` in view. So when click a button to add person, button's command object will update this collection and view will be refreshed automatically without having you to add it manually to data grid.

Comment: Thanks for the direction! I will re work everything from ground up

Answer (score 1):

I am also pretty new to WPF, C# and MVVM. I have read quite a fair bit for these two to three months, so maybe I'll share what I understood.

1. You seem to have the same question that I had a week or two ago. Data should not be stored in the model. Models are just data structures. Databases (or simulated alternatives like `List`s) are the actual storages that store these data. Some people would simply keep them in ViewModel, while some would move them to something outside of MVVM (e.g. a "Repository" class).
2. You are doing it all wrong. In MVVM, Views do not interact with ViewModels in this manner - they interact via `Command`s and Bindings. The fact that your View is directly manipulating the list means that it's definitely wrong.

Example:

View (Window):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MyViewModel x:Key="MyVM" />
</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="MyVM" />
</Window.DataContext>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleList}" ..... >
<Button Command="{Binding StoreCommand}" .... >
```

ViewModel:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PeopleListProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("PeopleList",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>),
    typeof(ViewModel));

public ObservableCollection<Person> PeopleList
{
    get
    {
        return GetValue(PeopleListProperty) as ObservableCollection<EmissionEntry>;
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(PeopleListProperty, value);
    }
}

private ICommand _storeCommand;
public ICommand StoreCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_storeCommand == null)
            _storeCommand = new MyCommandImplementation();
        return _storeCommand;
    }
}
```

`Person` is your model class with name/age etc. The list is kept in ViewModel, unless you want to have a repository somewhere.

You probably haven't really read anything about `ICommand`, so I suggest reading it up first. It is too long to give a tutorial here, but you can ask questions after you have read up some.

Comment: Most of the information here is correct. However, YOU SHOULD NEVER use Dependency Properties in your Model/ViewModel. Dependency Properties are EXCLUSIVELY for use in the View class. Part of what they are used for is to help the XAML engine bind to properties.

Comment: Why would that be so? I have been using Dependency Properties more than INotifyPropertyChanged. It is, however, correct to say that Views must use Dependency Properties, because binding target MUST be a Dependency Property. Binding can be done on a Dependency Property source as far as I know. Unless there is something bad to use this approach. @Aron

Comment: Several reasons. a) DependencyObject is a WPF class, using it in a model breaks POCO, and removes the key advantage of WPF/MVVM, which is decoupling from your view tech. Meaning that testing is harder b) The WPF team did a LOT of work to make sure WPF/Binding will marshel INPC back to the UI thread (which is another thing that helps with decoupling from the UI tech, shame about CollectionViews). DependencyProperties may ONLY be accessed from the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks guys, you guys gave some directions now